GCP error when trying to build and push image to container
I am in the process of trying to execute a Cloud Run job by following this guide At the step where I'm trying to push containers to the Google Cloud Container Registry using the Google Cloud SDK I get:
Executing command:
export SERVICE_NAME=parallel-job
gcloud builds submit \
    --pack image=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casentric-classifier/my-repo/${SERVICE_NAME}

Gives this error:
Successfully built image 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casentric-classifier/my-repo/parallel-job'
PUSH
Pushing us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casentric-classifier/my-repo/parallel-job
The push refers to repository [us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casentric-classifier/my-repo/parallel-job]
744c9ff06f7e: Preparing
0bb83f7438cd: Preparing
792a42128dc1: Preparing
3e933186f9b6: Preparing
36f9de0748c4: Preparing
8e9f20ffb142: Preparing
79971806f283: Preparing
9025ac911ca6: Preparing
dc2bd61bfaf6: Preparing
6213d5ec7fee: Preparing
629ca62fb7c7: Preparing
8e9f20ffb142: Waiting
79971806f283: Waiting
9025ac911ca6: Waiting
dc2bd61bfaf6: Waiting
6213d5ec7fee: Waiting
629ca62fb7c7: Waiting
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/casentric-classifier/locations/us-central1/repositories/my-repo" (or it may not exist)
Pushing us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casentric-classifier/my-repo/parallel-job
The push refers to repository [us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/casentric-classifier/my-repo/parallel-job]


I am new to this process and would appreciate any help in figuring out what I may have configured incorrectly.
Thanks.
I have checked permissions to the repository and they seem to be sufficient and have fun the following commands:
Log into gcloud:
gcloud auth login


Configure docker:
gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev


This post might be better suited for DevOps.

Is more than likely to be an IAM issue. Have you checked this part of the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorials/execute-cloud-run-jobs#before-you-begin

thank you MrThompson.  Yes I've gone through and set up IAM permissions per the tutorial.  I even just created a new project and went through all the steps again only to get the same error unfortunately.
